# Find max values in each rows of Spark data frame in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input `spark-dataframe` named `df` as,

```
+---------------+---+---+---+---+
|     CustomerID| P1| P2| P3| P4|
+---------------+---+---+---+---+
|         725153|  5|  6|  7|  8|
|         873008|  7|  8|  1|  2|
|         725116|  5|  6|  3|  2|
|         725110|  0|  1|  2|  5|
+---------------+---+---+---+---+
```

Among `P1,P2,P3,P4` I need to find the maximum 2 values for each `CustomerID`. And get the equivalent `column name` and put in it the `df`.So that my resultant `dataframe` should be,

```
+---------------+----+----+
|     CustomerID|col1|col2|
+---------------+----+----+
|         725153|  P4|  P3|
|         873008|  P2|  P1|
|         725116|  P2|  P1|
|         725110|  P4|  P3|
+---------------+----+----+
```

Here for the first row, `8` and `7` were the maximum values. Each equivalent column name is `P4` and `P3`. So that for its particular `CustomerID`, it should contain values `P4` and `P3`. This can be achieved in `pyspark` by using `pandas` dataframe.

```
nlargest = 2
order = np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :nlargest]
result = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[order],columns=['top{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, nlargest+1)],index=recommend_df.index)
```

But how can I achieve this in `scala`?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? can you post what you have tried here please ?

Comment: @eliasah I knew how to achieve this in `pyspark`. As we have `pandas` library there. So I am looking for the replacement of pandas here.

Comment: I meant in pyspark.

Comment: @eliasah I have added the solution for `pyspark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UDF` to get your desired result. In `UDF` you can `zip` all the column names with their respective value and then sort the `Array` according to the value and finally return top two column names from it. Below is the code for same.

```
//get all the columns that you want
val requiredCol = df.columns.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2!=0).map(_._1) 
//define a UDF which sorts according to the value and returns top two column names
val topTwoColumns = udf((seq: Seq[Int]) =>
  seq.zip(requiredCol).
    sortBy(_._1)(Ordering[Int].reverse).
    take(2).map(_._2))
```

Now you can use `withColumn` and pass your column values as an `array` to previously defined UDF.

```
df.withColumn("col", topTwoColumns(array(requiredCol.map(col(_)):_*))).
  select($"CustomerID",
    $"col".getItem(0).as("col1"),
    $"col".getItem(1).as("col2")).show

//output
//+----------+----+----+
//|CustomerID|col1|col2|
//+----------+----+----+
//|    725153|  P4|  P3|
//|    873008|  P2|  P1|
//|    725116|  P2|  P1|
//|    725110|  P4|  P3|
//+----------+----+----+
```

Comment: What is this array() function? what it does?

Comment: It Creates a new array column. You need to have `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` to use all the spark-sql function. You can find more on this https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array(java.lang.String,%20scala.collection.Seq)

Comment: How can I generalize this function? I mean without specifying that column names `P1,P2,P3,P4` how can I call `UDF` by passing column values as an `array`?

Comment: You can use `df.columns` which returns column names as an `Array` of `String`. You need to filter out your required columns from `df.columns`.  Like in the above case `df.columns.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2!=0).map(_._1)` will give you desired result and you can replace it with the hardcoded Array.

Comment: Thanks. Am clear with your solution. But am getting error after converting this into a generalized solution. `error : type mismatch; found : Array[String] required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column`. The `array()` function requires `cols*`. It does not accept `Array[String]`. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Where did you replaced it? You need to replace `Array("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4")` with `df.columns.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2!=0).map(_._1)` and it should work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176217/discussion-between-priya-m-and-vindev).